# How do I set margins for my Android app table?

Tags: java, android

I am trying a add rows to my table by pressing a button, I can add the rows but I don't know how to add layout to the added row.

Here is my code:

```
    public void testRow(View view) {
    // get a reference for the TableLayout
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.accountTable);

    // create a new TableRow
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);


    TextView x = new TextView(this);
    x.setText("text ");
    row.addView(x);

    TextView y = new TextView(this);
    y.setText("text ");
    row.addView(y);

    TextView z = new TextView(this);
    z.setText("text ");
    row.addView(z);

    // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    table.addView(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `TableRow` to `TableLayout` with `LayoutParams`, then you can also set the margins with it:

```
LayoutParams params = table.generateDefaultLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin = ...
params.rightMargin = ...
table.addView(row, params);
```